# how to change the backgroundcolor of a icon

Tags: jquery-mobile

i want to set different background colors to icons in buttons.
For example i want to change the background color of the info icon to NAVY

This is what i tried

in HTML

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="info" class="icon-navy" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
```

now the in generated button the icon get matched css rules .ui-icon the link has rules icon-navy.

Is there a way to look if there is a child for .icon-navy with id .ui-icon and set the backcolor like

```
$('.icon-navy .ui-icon').css({'background-color':'navy'});
```

Comment: Have you looked at the theme options? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-themes.html

Comment: yes i have but thats is for global settings, i want to be able to dynamicly change the bakcground of the icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.ui-icon-info {
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
```

jQuery prepends `.ui-icon` before the `data-icon` attribute.

Dynamically changing the color: `$('.ui-icon-info').css("background-color", "red");`

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/LVnZw/

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, you have to create a new css class like

```
.ui-listview.customIconColor .ui-icon{
    background-color: #0fc21a /*{global-icon-color}*/;
    background-color: rgba(.05,.9,.1,.9) /*{global-icon-disc}*/;
}
```

and insert this class to your

```
<ul class="customIconColor "></ul>
```

tags and it works fine for me. In your case, insert it into the

```
<a></a>
```

tags maybe. And check the data-role, for me it was a listview, modify the CSS class as you like.